# Ionic serve command landing on to balnk screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I run the command "ionic serve" landed to blank screen.
I have installed all the node modules using "npm install" & and after that run "ionic serve"

```
[app-scripts] [11:28:17]  tslint: ...p_source_code/ionicecommerce_muzammul/src/pages/select-country/select-country.ts, line: 8
[app-scripts]             All imports on this line are unused.
[app-scripts]        L7:  import { ConfigProvider } from '../../providers/config/config';
[app-scripts]        L8:  import { Http } from '@angular/http';
[app-scripts]        L9:  import { LoadingProvider } from '../../providers/loading/loading';
[app-scripts] [11:28:17]  tslint: ...f/app_source_code/ionicecommerce_muzammul/src/pages/select-zones/select-zones.ts, line: 8
[app-scripts] [11:28:17]  tslint: .../Users/Saif/app_source_code/ionicecommerce_muzammul/src/auth/auththentication.ts, line: 2
[app-scripts] [11:28:17]  tslint: .../Users/Saif/app_source_code/ionicecommerce_muzammul/src/auth/auththentication.ts, line: 3
[app-scripts] [11:28:17]  tslint: .../Saif/app_source_code/ionicecommerce_muzammul/src/pages/my-account/my-account.ts, line: 53
[app-scripts]             All imports on this line are unused.
[app-scripts]        L7:  import { ConfigProvider } from '../../providers/config/config';
[app-scripts]        L8:  import { Http } from '@angular/http';
[app-scripts]        L9:  import { LoadingProvider } from '../../providers/loading/loading';
[app-scripts]             All imports on this line are unused.
[app-scripts]        L1:  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
[app-scripts]        L2:  import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
[app-scripts]        L3:  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
[app-scripts]             All imports on this line are unused.
[app-scripts]        L2:  import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
[app-scripts]        L3:  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
[app-scripts]        L4:  @Injectable()
[app-scripts]             'currenrtPassword' is declared but never used.
[app-scripts]       L52:  //this.shared.customerData.password="1234"
[app-scripts]       L53:  let currenrtPassword = this.myAccountData.currentPassword;
[app-scripts]       L54:  let newPassword = this.myAccountData.password;
[app-scripts]             'newPassword' is declared but never used.
[app-scripts]       L53:  let currenrtPassword = this.myAccountData.currentPassword;
[app-scripts]       L54:  let newPassword = this.myAccountData.password;
[app-scripts]       L55:  // console.log(currenrtPassword + "  " + newPassword);
[app-scripts]             'require' is declared but never used.
[app-scripts]       L22:  declare var braintree;
[app-scripts]       L23:  declare var require: any
[app-scripts]       L24:  declare var Buffer: any
[app-scripts]             'Buffer' is declared but never used.
[app-scripts]       L23:  declare var require: any
[app-scripts]       L24:  declare var Buffer: any
[app-scripts] [11:28:17]  tslint: .../Saif/app_source_code/ionicecommerce_muzammul/src/pages/my-account/my-account.ts, line: 54
[app-scripts] [11:28:17]  tslint: C:/Users/Saif/app_source_code/ionicecommerce_muzammul/src/pages/order/order.ts, line: 23
[app-scripts] [11:28:17]  tslint: C:/Users/Saif/app_source_code/ionicecommerce_muzammul/src/pages/order/order.ts, line: 24
[app-scripts] [11:28:17]  lint finished in 6.25 s
```

After running ionic serve i am getting this on my console window & blank screen open on my browser. Development server runs on localhost:8100

Comment: did copy your files from other project ?

Comment: No, it's a purchased product.

Comment: open files using VS code or any editor and check if there is any errors in code

Comment: i did that but i cant't see any error in the code.

Comment: run -  npm audit fix -  to check your project or , run - npm run ionic:serve - to run it

Comment: this app is build on ionic and angular, do i need to run any angular related commands also ?

Comment: what i write is ionic and angular syntax , but the what you post is a normal thing for ionic project build and not an error , check your code and dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Hey its your code have unused `declarations` and `imports`

In your code editor add plugin called `tslint`  it will show lint issues

EG:-->

```
import { LoadingProvider } from '../../providers/loading/loading';
[app-scripts]             All imports on this line are unused.
```